# Snap svg: click event fired at the end of drag

Tags: javascript, snap.svg

As the title says, the click event fires automatically after the end of drag. This is what I have:

```
<svg id="testCanvas" viewBox="0 0 1000 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%"/>
```

and:

```
var s = Snap('#testCanvas');
ii = s.image('oneBookTest/scania.svg', 10, 10, 100, 100);
ii.drag().click(function(){console.log('click');});
```

The drag works fine but fires the "click" event when drag ends (mouseup). I've tried with:

```
ii.mouseup(function(e){e.preventDefault();});
```

but to no avail. Is this the expected behaviour? Can it be avoided with something less hacky than a "justDragged" variable and a setTimeout?

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/98JJ5/3/

Comment: Sometimes a flag seems the best way to go. I'd pop the example on a jsfiddle though.

Comment: Also, why not remove the click handler you've added. I suspect this is part of a bigger problem, but I think you still need to highlight the problem showing why you need to add a click handler (as you don't want it to fire).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the ideas. I'm going with a flag at the moment. I need the click because I want something to happen when user clicks on the image. I'm coding something like an image editor, so I need the user to be able to click and to be able to drag, different things. How do you add Snap.svg to the jsfiddle?

Comment: You can use a cdn and add to the lhs additional resources in a fiddle, or you could just google snap jsfiddle, and fork one that already exists (changing options etc). If doing it a lot, it may be worth setting up a basic snap example in your account that you can then fork/clone or something.